# Building specific GNOME release with JHBuild?

Tags: gnome, jhbuild

I use CentOS 7 and like it, but want to use newer gnome-shell releases, but would prefer the current stable release and not the development version.

How do I choose/build a specific release (e.g. 3.18.1) using JHBuild?

Comment: @don_crissti Using other newer components would be a bonus. My question is about building a specific release, not about choosing specific components.

Comment: I could also use Debian unstable, but I like a stable base with cherry picked newer versions. gnome-shell 3.8.4 has some specific flaws.

Answer (score 3):

The GNOME release team publishes [`modulesets`](https://download.gnome.org/teams/releng/) for each GNOME release that can be used to build that particular version of GNOME.
Now, if you read the `jhbuild` documentation, section [Configuration File Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/config-reference.html.en):

> moduleset
>
> A string or list of strings specifying the name(s) of the module
>   set(s) to use. This can either be the filename of a moduleset included
>   with JHBuild (excluding the path and extension), or a full HTTP URL to
>   an externally managed moduleset.

So to use `3.18.1` modulesets edit `~/.config/jhbuildrc` and modify `moduleset` e.g. assuming you've downloaded the `3.18.1` modulesets from gnome site in `jhbuild/modulesets`:

```
moduleset = [ 'gnome-apps-3.18.1' ]
```

or you could pass the URL:

```
moduleset = 'https://download.gnome.org/teams/releng/3.18.1/gnome-apps-3.18.1.modules'
```

or if you want to build with dependencies

```
moduleset = [ 'gnome-suites-core-3.18.1', 'gnome-suites-core-deps-3.18.1', 'gnome-apps-3.18.1' ]
```

and `modules` to build e.g. the [UX meta module](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-modulesets):

```
modules = [ 'meta-gnome-core-shell' ]
```

and then build `gnome-shell`:

```
jhbuild build gnome-shell
```

This is a very simplistic answer. Please read the official docs, especially [*BuildGnome - Introduction*](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildGnome), the manual linked above and [*HowDoI - jhbuild*](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild). See also [developing `gnome-shell` under `jhbuild`](http://blog.thismagpie.com/2013/08/developing-gnome-shell-under-jhbuild.html).

Comment: I edited `~/.config/jhbuildrc`:
`moduleset = 'https://download.gnome.org/teams/releng/3.33.2/gnome-apps-3.33.2.modules'
`
but:
`jhbuild update: could not download https://download.gnome.org/teams/releng/3.33.2/gnome-apps-3.33.2.modules: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
`